# Can I remove the [code] button in a rmarkdown html_document while still displaying the code with the [Show/Hide All Code] button

Tags: css, r, r-markdown, knitr

While I like the possibility to show/hide all code that is allowed by the `code_folding` property of the `html_document` output in rmarkdown, I do not like that I have to see a `Code` button everywhere there is some code because it creates "empty line(s)" in the document.

Is there a way to remove this/these `Code` button(s) with a property or some javascript magic

- without altering the Rmd document (ie. not writing some additional code in the document itself)
- while still allowing to show/hide all code through the `Show/Hide All Code` toggle

Here is an example:

````
---                     
title: "Test"           
date: '`r Sys.Date()`'  
output:                 
 html_document:         
    code_download: true 
    code_folding: 'hide'
---                     
                        
# Title 1               
                        
chunk 1                 
                        
```{r, eval = FALSE}    
1+1                     
```                     
                        
```{r, eval = FALSE}    
1+2                     
```                     
                        
```{r}                  
1+3                     
```
````

Which renders like this:

[image]

Comment: You say you don't want to alter the document, are you ope to editing the yaml section to include a css file? you can set a css rule to hide the buttons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can hide the code-folding buttons with a css rule.

```yaml
---                     
title: "Test"           
date: '`r Sys.Date()`'  
output:                 
  html_document: 
    css: "style.css"        
    code_download: true 
    code_folding: 'hide'
---
```

The style.css

```css
.code-folding-btn {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: @yihui-xie wow! Thanks for the bounty! so unexpected!

Comment: Just my small token of appreciation :) Keep up the good work!